# Giving GNURoot root permissions

Tags: root-access

So before anything I wanted to say that I am a root user and I installed the GNURoot application from google play. So I have been playing around with the GNURoot app for 2-3 days, and I thought that it would be fun to try and make a reverse tcp connection from my laptop to my phone. So these are the commands I used:

On my phone:

```
root@localhost:/# nc -lp 443
```

On my computer:

```
root@potato:~$ nc 10.10.10.107 443
```

But I keep getting this error on my phone:

```
Can't grab 0.0.0.0:443 with bind : Permission denied
```

Google didn't help much, I know that for ports under 1024 you need admin/root access, but GNURoot never asked for it. What should I do

Comment: Ask the dev to implement it. From the user's end, there's nothing you can do: An app must *ask* for root access, simply "granting" that doesn't help.

Comment: @Izzy I have tested it with ports 1024 and up and it works just fine

Comment: If you're satisfied with that and consider it a solution, feel free to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and [accept the answer](/help/accepted-answer) then. You can of course include my above comment for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to the question is to use ports above 1024 or as @Izzy suggested to ask the dev to implement root access (as an app *must ask* to perform root operations, simply "granting it permission" would not help as the app would not know to (properly) make use of it).